# Transfer files "directly" from Android to iPhone

Tags: iphone, file-sharing, android, file-transfer

My friend (iPhone 13 I guess) and I (Pixel 7) want to share photos and videos we took with each other.
We use some messaging app which allows it. But it's a hassle selecting and transferring.
I'd like not to use another service if I don't have to.

I wondered if there's a way to directly transfer images and video.
I tried it with cable with my work iphone SE. At first Android recognized it as storage. But then all data transfer options are gone and it can only be charged.

Is there any method to share files either via cable or wirelessly via Bluetooth, NFC, Wifi?

Comment: Zapya is fine just install it on both phones and send and receive as many files as you'd like, it doesn't need an internet connection to work either works under the same wifi easily it even creates a hotspot if you don't have a wifi, Bluetooth is slow it takes ages to transfer a file even if Bluetooth worked on an iPhone in the way it should which it doesn't, NFC is not exactly for sending files as far as I know...

Comment: Apps like `Snapdrop` and `Copy My Data` allow you to share files between devices by scanning a QR code from one device with the other. There is another online platform `sendbig.com` which allows you to transfer unlimited files up to 30GB for Free from Android to iPhone or any other device. There is also a third-party tool like "EaseUS MobiMover" which offers cross-platform data transfer options. You can see the complete details here https://mobi.easeus.com/mobile-transfer/how-to-transfer-files-from-iphone-to-android-wirelessly.html for using It.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different options for transferring files directly from an Android device to an iPhone:

- **By using third-party applications:**
  SHAREit, Xender, Send Anywhere, Feem, Zapya & more.
  These apps typically use a WiFi connection to transfer the files and support a wide variety of file types.
- **By using cloud storage applications:**
  Google Drive, iCloud, DropBox, Box, & more.
  You can upload the files to the cloud and share access using invite or share to all.
- **Social media apps:**
  Telegram, WhatsApp & more.
  Share with more flexibility.
- **By Cable:**
  To transfer files directly from an Android device to an iPhone using a cable, you'll need a USB-C to Lightning cable.
  Here's how to do it:

1. Connect one end of the cable to your Android device and the other end to your iPhone.
2. On your Android device, go to "Settings" > "Storage" > "Files" and select the files you want to transfer.
   Tap the "Share" button and select "Send files".
3. On your iPhone, the "Files" app should automatically open. Select "Import" to import the files from your Android device.
4. If the "Files" app doesn't open automatically, you can find it on your iPhone's home screen.

Comment: Android 14: I do not have a "send files" choice under my sharing options.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to accomplish this is with shared photo albums in iCloud and whatever the Google equivalent is (Google Drive?). OneDrive and DropBox support this as well.

You can’t use a direct cable, but there are USB flash drives with Lightning connectors. You can share the flash drive between phones if you really need an offline solution.

Finally, you can sync both phones to a computer to share the photos